# Equation Writing Help for Age Problem

Tags: word-problem

> A mother's age is $3$ times older than her older son and $7$ times older than her
>   younger son (She has only two sons). The older son will be $50$ years old
>   when the younger son is same age as his mother's current age. What is
>   the mother's current age?

Let's call them as $M$, $O$ and $Y$.

$$M = 3O \tag{1}$$
$$M=7Y \tag {2}$$

and

$$O - Y = 50 - M\tag{3}$$

This is where I'm stuck. Can you take a look?

With My Warnest Regards!

Comment: What is $B$...?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that! I meant Older son, which is $O$.

Comment: Edited the question. Now it seems more clear.

Comment: Check my edit on 3rd equation. Btw, what exactly is the problem, you got 3 equations and 3 unknowns, should be easy to solve imho.

Comment: @mike239x Yes, but the most important thing is to specify how you found it.

Comment: The equation or the solution?

Comment: @mike239x Definelity the equation.

Comment: Well, I had solved a lot of similar tasks as I was younger, that is how. But for real: as time passes the age difference between older and younger bro-s doesn't change, so I wrote it for 'now' and 'as older bro gets 50', made an equation out of it.

Answer (score 1):

$$M=3O =7Y$$

The younger will have the mother's age after $\color {green}{M-Y} $ years.
after the same periode, the Older will have $O+\color {green}{M-Y} $.
thus

$$50=O+(M-Y) $$
$$=O+6Y $$
$$150=3O+18Y=7Y+18Y $$
$$Y=6$$
$$M=42$$
$$O=14$$

In $36$ years, the younger will have
$6+36=42$ the age of the mother, while the older will have $14+36=50$.

Comment: Can you explain how you found this $50=O+(M-Y)$? I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Busi  Y becomes M after $(( M-Y))$ years.O will have $O+((M-Y)) $

Comment: However, why we subtracted the ages and added $O$?

Comment: For example , If you have 10 years. you will have 17 years in $17-10$.

Comment: I still didn't get what you mean :/ Also why is it $150$? I wish you could give an explanation on your answer.

Comment: @Busi The younger will have the age of the mother in $M-Y $ years. at the same time, the older will grow by the same time.He will have $O+(M-Y) $.

Comment: For $150$, why is it $150$?

Comment: @Busi I multiplied by 3 to eliminate O.

Comment: @Busi Now it is clear . You will get it.

Comment: Great! but $150=3O+18Y=7Y+18Y$ this step still makes me confused. I mean why not $50$, $50=3O+18Y=7Y+18Y$

Comment: $50=O+(M-Y) =O+6Y$ if we multiply by $3$ we get $150=3O+18Y $ but $3O=7Y $.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be some amount of time which has past. Surely this approach is more clear (at least in my opinion), although it is longer.

$50=O+x$

$x+Y=M$

So your $4$ equations are:

$$x+Y=M$$

$$50=O+x$$

$$M=3O$$
$$M=7Y$$

Substituting the 3rd and 4th equations:$$3O=7Y$$

$$O=\dfrac{7Y}3$$

Substituting for $O$ into the second equation:

$$50=\dfrac{7Y}3+x$$

And rewording the first equation by substituting $M$:$$x+Y=7Y \implies 0=x-6Y$$

Subtracting this from the equation you just got:$$50=\dfrac{7Y}3-(-6Y)\implies150=7Y+18Y\implies Y=6$$

You now know the age of the younger son is $6$, and you should be able to solve for the age of the mother and the older son.

Comment: If you can explain how you wrote the equations, I'd be grateful. What I mean is I want to know how to write an equation.

Comment: You had the 3rd and 4th equations.

Comment: @busi Now you have to think of the first and second equations.

Comment: The older son will be 50 after some amount of that time, let that time be $x$, $50=O+x$

Comment: @Busi The younger son will be the mother's age ($M$) after that same amount of time, so $M=Y+x$. I hope I could provide a good explanation.

Comment: I didn't get your answer.

Comment: Also can I use your method for every question?

Comment: @Busi every question? What types of questions are you talking about, and what do you not understand about this?

Comment: I really got nothing from your answer, like kind of these questions.

Comment: @Busi What is the FIRST thing you do not understand.

Comment: How you made the equations and wrote $150$ instead of $50$.

Comment: @Busi For this step: $$50=\dfrac{7Y}3-(-6Y)\implies150=7Y+18Y$$ I multiplied both sides by $3$.

Comment: Oh, good. Now how did you write the equations? It helped me to write it by $x$.

Comment: I explained that in this extended discussion.

Comment: I will fail on my math exam 100%. There's no chance to understand these questions because I still didn't understand it.

Comment: @Busi, one tip: Write your equations EXACTLY as your question has worded. Whenever you are trying to solve for something, let that somethin be $x$.

Comment: can you open a chat? we can discuss there if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74315/discussion-between-idk-and-busi).